# Connecting to two networks at once and specifying programs to work on each?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Internet in my area is pretty bad, it is suitable at least for web browsing and watching videos, but not for gaming.

What I had in mind was purchasing a 4G LTE hotspot with a data plan, which gets a great connection and speed, and then connecting to it on my home computer, which would also be connected to the ethernet from my ISP.

I already know that my computer can connect to both of these networks at once, but my big question here is to filter how programs would use each network.

Ideally, I want **only** a program that I would specify, like a game, to work through the 4G LTE hotspot, and then all other normal internet procedures to work through the ethernet so data usage on the hotspot isn't huge.

How would I go about doing the above? Is there some sort of functionality in Windows that I am glancing over, or a program that could easily to this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** As an alternative, I had an idea with routing but I'm not sure if it would work, I don't have too much experience in it. For the 4G LTE hotspot, is it possible to say that "all network traffic going to this IP in Chicago will work" for example, and force all other network traffic going **ANYWHERE** else to the other network?

Comment: Common question, but no one likes the answer:  The OS and its applications are not designed to function this way, and while there are hacks available (http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) they are far from a clean solution. the Correct solution is to use routing rules to direct traffic out an interface, but routes are destination dependent, without regard for the application in question, so you can say "all apps going to server X use this nic", but you can't say "app1 uses nic1 to reach serverX but app2 uses nic2 to reach that same server".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I use firewall rules specific to the hotspot I had in mind to block all programs but the one I wanted to go through? Is it possible that the blocked programs would default to the other network?

Comment: I THINK you can do something like that with the IPTables firewall, but not the windows one.

Comment: Yeah, windows isnt the way to do this. If you wanted to get into it then a PFSense gateway would be my approach, but thats far from plug and play.